how to maintain position() of inner element node while applying template at its outer node level in xslt

For each "author", I need to create an "authordetails" element in the output with "sno" element inside it.


Whenever "otherbooks" tag is present in "author", I need to create that many number of "sno" tags inside that particular "authordetails" (as shown in the example).
If there are no "otherbooks" tag present, then I need to create a single "sno" inside the "authordetails".
"sno" is a kind of unique number and incremental.

2)My second question would be, I would like to generate a uuid for each "author". How do I accomplish that with xslt. I'm using SaxonC-HE version.
INPUT XML:
<authors>
    <author>
        <fname>Harper</fname>
        <surname>Lee</surname>
        <email>francis.rand@hotmail.com</email>
        <title>To Kill a Mockingbird</title>
        <price>4.51</price>
    </author>
    <author>
        <fname>Abi</fname>
        <surname>Dare</surname>
        <email>thomasina176@gmail.com</email>
        <title>The Girl with the Louding Voice</title>
        <price>69.83</price>
    </author>
    <author>
        <fname>Rowling</fname>
        <surname>J.K.</surname>
        <email>jk@yahoo.com</email>
        <title>Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone</title>
        <price>46.84</price>
        <otherbooks>
            <book>
                <name>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets</name>
                <date>1991-12-23</date>
            </book>
            <book>
                <name>Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban</name>
                <date>1992-11-20</date>
            </book>
        </otherbooks>
    </author>
    <author>
        <fname>Max</fname>
        <surname>Porter</surname>
        <email>melinda17674@hotmail.com</email>
        <title>Lanny</title>
        <price>34.95</price>
    </author>
    <author>
        <fname>Narayan</fname>
        <surname>R.K./surname>
            <email>chae5@yahoo.com</email>
            <title>Malgudi Days</title>
            <price>21.35</price>
            <otherbooks>
                <book>
                    <name>Swami and Friends</name>
                    <date>1988-07-24</date>
                </book>
                <book>
                    <name>The Guide</name>
                    <date>1968-03-25</date>
                </book>
            </otherbooks>
        </author>
    </authors>`

EXPECTED OUTPUT XML:
<data>
    <authordetails>
        <name>Harper</name>
        <email>francis.rand@hotmail.com</email>
        <sno>1</sno>
    </authordetails>
    <authordetails>
        <name>Abi</name>
        <email>thomasina176@gmail.com</email>
        <sno>2</sno>
    </authordetails>
    <authordetails>
        <name>Rowling</name>
        <email>jk@yahoo.com</email>
        <sno>3</sno>
        <sno>4</sno>
    </authordetails>
    <authordetails>
        <name>Max</name>
        <email>melinda17674@hotmail.com</email>
        <sno>5</sno>
    </authordetails>
    <authordetails>
        <name>Narayan</name>
        <email>chae5@yahoo.com</email>
        <sno>6</sno>
        <sno>7</sno>
    </authordetails>
</data>

ACTUAL OUTPUT XML that I get:
<data>
    <authordetails>
        <name>Harper</name>
        <email>francis.rand@hotmail.com</email>
        <sno>1</sno>
    </authordetails>
    <authordetails>
        <name>Abi</name>
        <email>thomasina176@gmail.com</email>
        <sno>2</sno>
    </authordetails>
    <authordetails>
        <name>Rowling</name>
        <email>jk@yahoo.com</email>
        <sno>1</sno>
        <sno>2</sno>
    </authordetails>
    <authordetails>
        <name>Max</name>
        <email>melinda17674@hotmail.com</email>
        <sno>4</sno>
    </authordetails>
    <authordetails>
        <name>Narayan</name>
        <email>chae5@yahoo.com</email>
        <sno>1</sno>
        <sno>2</sno>
    </authordetails>
</data>

XSL Stylesheet that I used:
<xsl:template match="authors/author" mode="author">
    <authordetails>
        <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="fname" />
        </name>
        <email>
            <xsl:value-of select="email" />
        </email>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="otherbooks/book">
                <xsl:for-each select="otherbooks/book">
                    <sno>
                        <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                    </sno>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <sno>
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                </sno>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </authordetails>
</xsl:template>

I tried the above code but when I parse through "otherbooks" element, the position of outer element "authordetails" is lost and is resetted (to "otherbooks" position) and provides "sno" as 1 and 2 everytime. Could anyone help?

SaxonC in the suppported version (12) is an XSLT 3 processor so why is this question tagged for Saxon and talking about SaxonC but using the xslt-2.0 tag and not the xslt-3.0 tag?

Alternative suggestion:
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="3.0" expand-text="yes">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="author">
    <authordetails>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fname, email, otherbooks/book"/>
      <xsl:if test="empty(otherbooks)">
         <xsl:call-template name="sno"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </authordetails>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="otherbooks/book" name="sno">
    <sno>
      <xsl:number count="author[empty(otherbooks)] | otherbooks/book" level="any"/>
    </sno>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="author/fname">
    <name>{.}</name>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>

As for the UUID problem, your best bet might be to generate a file containing a suitable number of UUIDs and read them into a global variable in your stylesheet using unparsed-text(). Then the author template can pick the UUID at the appropriate position in this list.

Assuming you use a SaxonC version that supports XSLT 3 you could use an accumulator
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="sno" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="authors" select="0"/>
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="authors/author" select="$value + 1"/>
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="authors/author/otherbooks/book[position() gt 1]" select="$value + 1"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:template match="author">
    <authordetails>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fname, email"/>
      <xsl:sequence>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="otherbooks/book"/>
        <xsl:on-empty>
          <sno>{accumulator-before('sno')}</sno>
        </xsl:on-empty>
      </xsl:sequence>
    </authordetails>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="otherbooks/book">
        <sno>{accumulator-before('sno')}</sno>    
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="author/fname">
    <name>{.}</name>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="sno"/>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>


thanks, let me try this solution. Also, any idea on the 2nd question?

@user24663487, I am not sure how an uuid looks/is defined, in general for Saxon Java I would suggest into writing an extension function that calls into Java (e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID--), in the context of SaxonC this is however not possible or easily achievable. I have found one XSLT 2 attempt to generate a uuid https://gist.github.com/azinneera/778f69ae6b0049b5edcd69da70072405, but I haven't checked its quality.
